# Importing txt file. error with non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r

I am trying to import a txt file. I'm having trouble reading the `rf` column.

Here is the link to the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/t7vhucub0jr583x/test.csv?dl=0

Get an error:

```
Message : error with non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Comment: And what script are you using so far?

Answer (score 0):

Load the file with `read.csv`, custom separator, custom decimal separator and `stringsAs.

```
data <- read.csv("<path>", sep = ";", dec = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Now the `rf` column is available:

```
data$rf
```

Comment: I changed the file to a csv.file. The problem now is that the "rm" and "rmrf" columns doesn't change to period like the other columns. These two columns are the only ones that have comma. And then I can't calculate mean(rmrf) or sd(rmrf).
This warning message shows up: "Warning message:
In mean.default(mkt) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"
What does it mean that "The following objects are masked from test"?
I'm not good in R. Please desribe carefully:) thank you